# Is there a way to plot seaborn KDE on a geographical map

Tags: python, seaborn, matplotlib-basemap, kernel-density, geography

I am trying to show the density of geographical points using Basemap and seaborn :

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(9, 9))
# plot coastlines with basemap
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='c',
            llcrnrlat=bbox[0],urcrnrlat=bbox[1],
            llcrnrlon=bbox[2],urcrnrlon=bbox[3])
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#DDEEFF')
m.fillcontinents(color='#FFEEDD')
m.drawcoastlines(color='gray', zorder=2)
m.drawcountries(color='gray', zorder=2)

sns.kdeplot(df_toplot['longitude'], df_toplot['latitude'], \
            shade=True, cmap='Purples', \
            ax=ax);
```

The result is not that good
[The superposition of the two features is overlaping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSXkn.png)
Is there a simple way to display the density of the points more properly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried providing a high scalar number to the `zorder` argument in the `kdeplot` function? It should look like this:

```
sns.kdeplot(df_toplot['longitude'], df_toplot['latitude'], \
            shade=True, cmap='Purples', \
            ax=ax, zorder=100);
```

Comment: Specifying any value for `zorder` argument make the map disappear and only the `kdeplot` is displayed.